# Jupyter Notebook kernel not upgrading

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I currently use python 3.7.4. I am trying to upgrade to python 3.8 by using a new environment. The following steps were executed in Anaconda prompt:

```
conda install ipykernel
conda create -n py38 python=3.8
Activate py38
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --name py38
```

Then, I restarted Anaconda, and ran "jupyter notebook". In the top right corner within Jupyter notebook, the kernel shows "py38".
However, when running the following code :

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

It returns:

```
3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: Is `py3.8` your default environment? Every time you start Anaconda, it places you in the default.

Comment: No. But when activating this environment, it is giving serveral conflicts and incompatibilities. I guess it's too early to be using 3.8 in combination with Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

Run `conda install nb_conda` from the anaconda prompt in your py38 environment.

Launch a notebook with `jupyter notebook` in your activate conda environment in this case py38.

Then create a new notebook and you can select the environment you want in this case py38.

After you have done this try running:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

and see the output.

Comment: Running conda_install nb_conda is giving my serveral conflicts. I think it's best to stick with python 3.7 for the moment.  The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package pip conflicts for:
nb_conda -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip
python=3.8 -> pip
Package ipython conflicts for:
nb_conda -> notebook[version='>=4.3.1'] -> ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0|>=4.0.0|>=5.0']
Package setuptools conflicts for:
nb_conda -> notebook[version='>=4.3.1'] -> jinja2 -> setuptools
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools
...................